# Is VMware Fusion open source?

Tags: vmware-fusion

I came across this: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=FUS-503-OSS&productId=294

It seems this may be the source code for VMware Fusion.  Is this for real?

Comment: Seems on-topic to me. VMWare Fusion includes a Pro version designed for server operators including simulating environments like cloud deployment.

Comment: I had the exact same question as the OP. I was wondering if VMware had an open source version of fusion when I saw that page, and I am an IT professional. So I don't find this question off topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not.
These are the open source *tools* used in VMWare Fusion, for which VMWare is required to distribute the source code in accordance with the tool's license agreement.